# Как каждый раз переопределять переменную с помощью for в JS

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Всем привет! Буду рад если поможете, очень долго уже сижу с этим.

```js
let video = document.querySelectorAll('.videopleer');

var start = video[0];
for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
    video[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        start.classList.remove('start');
        this.classList.add('start');
        start = this;
    })
}

function toggleVideoStatus() {

        if (video.paused) {
            video.play()
            stopBtnImg.src = '@img/controls__stop.png'
            playIntro.style.display = 'none';
            stopIntro.style.display = 'none';
            video.style.borderRadius = '0 40px 0 0px'
            controls.classList.add('controls__active')



        } else {
            video.pause()
            stopIntro.style.display = 'block';
            stopBtnImg.src = '@img/controls__play.png'


        }
    }
  video.addEventListener('click', toggleVideoStatus);
```

```css
.player {
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 0 30px 0 0 ;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
.videopleer {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 40px 0 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="player">
        <div class="video">
            <video class="videopleer__first videopleer"
                src="http://video.ted.com/talks/podcast/CraigVenter_2008_480.mp4">
            </video>
            <video class="videopleer__second videopleer" src="/sample-5s.webm">
                
            </video>
        </div>
<div>
```

У меня есть 2 видеоплеера. 1 работает но со вторым я понял что придется посидеть так как их 2. Почитав я понял что нужно их перебрать и уже через for выбрать то на какой нажимается. Я добился присвоение классов.

Но так как весь код был написан на 1 переменную **video().** сейчас ничего не работает из за того что **var video = document.querySelectorAll('.videopleer');**

Так вот:
Как можно после срабатывания for записать ***результат в переменную*** и **обновлять** при каждой итерации

Спасибо огромное заранее, извиняюсь что так много текста.
Если нужны будут еще какой то код или Jsfigin то смогу скинуть.

Comment: Почему не оставить только один плеер, тот который работает?

Comment: их нужно 2(( такое тз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно я не до-конца понял задачу. Просто записывай при клике в переменную start элемент на который произошел клик.
Вот решение:

```
var video = document.querySelectorAll('.videopleer');

for (var i = 0; i < video__all.length; i++) {
    video__all[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        video__all[0].classList.remove('start');
        video__all[i].classList.add('start');
        toggleVideoStatus(video__all[i])
    })
}

function toggleVideoStatus(video) {
    if (video.paused) {
        video.play()
        stopBtnImg.src = '@img/controls__stop.png'
        playIntro.style.display = 'none';
        stopIntro.style.display = 'none';
        video.style.borderRadius = '0 40px 0 0px'
        controls.classList.add('controls__active')
    } else {
        video.pause()
        stopIntro.style.display = 'block';
        stopBtnImg.src = '@img/controls__play.png'
    }
}
```

Вот как бы написал я:

```
let videos = document.querySelectorAll('.videopleer');

videos.forEach((video) => {
    video.addEventListener('click', () => {
        videos.forEach((el) => {
            el.classList.remove('start')
        })

        video.classList.add('start')
        toggleVideoStatus(video);
    })
})

function toggleVideoStatus(video) {
    if (video.paused) {
        video.play()
        stopBtnImg.src = '@img/controls__stop.png'
        playIntro.style.display = 'none';
        stopIntro.style.display = 'none';
        video.style.borderRadius = '0 40px 0 0px'
        controls.classList.add('controls__active')
    } else {
        video.pause()
        stopIntro.style.display = 'block';
        stopBtnImg.src = '@img/controls__play.png'
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю но суть в том что да при каждой итерации в **start** будет добавляться нужное значение но это только внутри **forEach*** если я хочу обратиться вне то он **undefined**. Вы не знаете как это решить))?

Comment: пример кода jsfiddle.net/yc12ot6u/6

Comment: @Адиль глобальные переменные?

Comment: @Адиль вот. Нужно было сразу весь свой код показать. Просто при клике вывывай функцию toggleVideoStatus и передавай переменную video в функцию. Сделал два варианта.

Comment: спасибо @Bakhtiyar